# Background filtering on images

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, javacv

I am new to image processing.

I am trying to find dominant colors in an object and avoid the background color (white, gray or black).

I am using java, and a library (wrapper over opencv), any other java alternatives are welcome.

Example of image:
https://cdn7.bigcommerce.com/s-6gf5gg/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/21736/50424/E43062_WAW_1__88633.1516835767.jpg?c=2

Comment: Is there a way to mask all gray colors? in case of rgb, something like (R=(G+-delta) =(B_-delta) with a delta?

Answer (score 0):

One way that I could have achieved the same is using the Eigen Vectors to find different colors present in an image.

You can check out these two links for further reference as they take you through the general implementation of finding primary colors in an image. While the second link gives you the information about what tools are present inside OpenCV to find primary colors & how we achieve this.

http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/dominant-color-implementation/

http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/dominant-color/